# grid items not aligning on the same row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I can't seem to understand why the ‘Char2,4,6 content’ divs are not aligned to their respective images on the right. They seem to be on different rows.

Here is the code if anyone would be kind enough to tell me why this is happening.

```css
.chars{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 20% 40%;
}

/* Setting all images of characters to fit in their cells. */
.chars img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.char1-img, .char3-img, .char5-img{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    grid-area: auto/1/auto/1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.char1-content,.char3-content,.char5-content{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-area: auto/2/auto/ span 3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.char2-img,.char4-img,.char6-img{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    grid-area: auto/3/auto/3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.char2-content,.char4-content,.char6-content{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-area: auto/1/auto/ span 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="chars">
  <div class="char1-img">
    <img src="./images/Leona.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="char1-content">
    <p>
      Leon Harper or rather Leona Harper is part of a creed of Assassins and spies who have the uncanny
      ability to morph into any face they desire so as long as it is of the same gender and once they are
      in
      contact of it with the intent of morphing, Leona however is special even among her peers due to her
      ability to not only swap faces but also into one of any man or woman this has undoubtedly led her to
      be
      one of the most proficient and competent among the rest despite being a new recruit placing her in
      high
      regards for the Elders in the Creed.
      Much to the confusion surrounding her actual gender she has occasionally put out that she prefers to
      spend most of her time as a woman and to be addressed as Leona rather than her male counterpart
      "Leon".
      Whatever the case may be no one can deny her stunningly enchanting appearance regardless of what she
      chooses to go by.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char2-img">
    <img src="./images/Elizabeth.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="char2-content">
    <p>
      Elizabeth Burnley, a once-promising doctor, scientist, and scholar in a world where those
      professions are distant memories. Raised in a post-apocalyptic realm ravaged by a relentless virus,
      Elizabeth's life took a tragic turn when she lost her father to the very disease he fought to cure.
      As she now navigates a harsh existence within a hidden vault, her journey as a doctor accompanying
      search parties outside takes an unexpected turn, challenging her to adapt and survive in a world
      where danger and mystery lurk at every corner.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char3-img">
    <img src="./images/abiha-al-farsi.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="char3-content">
    <p>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
      born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
      great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
      avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
      pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
      circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
      example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
      from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char4-img">
    <img src="./images/katrya.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="char4-content">
    <p>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
      born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
      great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
      avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
      pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
      circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
      example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
      from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char5-img">
    <img src="./images/1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="char5-content">
    <p>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
      born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
      great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
      avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
      pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
      circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
      example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
      from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char6-img">
    <img src="./images/9.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="char6-content">
    <p>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
      born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
      great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
      avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
      pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
      circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
      example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
      from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/Emerald-Wolf/pen/JjwRKQz

Here is a screenshot of the website with the images for a better view.

[image: problem]

As the image shows, the content for each image is on a new row beneath it not on the same row as the image, I’m quite confused because the content for the rows 1-3-5 is good.

I've tried overflow, white-space properties but i don't think that has anything to do with this? nothing really seems to make sense as the cells should make use of the empty space above them.

Comment: Add `grid-auto-flow: dense` to the grid container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue #1

You're using `grid-row-start: auto` and `grid-row-end: auto` to place your items (represented in your code as `grid-area: auto/1/auto/span 2`, as one example).

This allows the grid algorithm to place your items in sequential rows.

### Issue #2

The sequence of placement of items is guided by their order in the HTML.

You have the image elements listed before the content elements.

[image]

This works for rows 1, 3 and 5, because the image is supposed to appear before the content.

But it fails for rows 2, 4, and 6 because you want the reverse: content first, image second. But you have the row placements in the CSS set to `auto` and specific column placements; and the images ordered first in the HTML. So new rows must be created.

### Solution: `grid-auto-flow: dense`

With `grid-auto-flow: dense`, items set to `auto` placement are instructed to fill empty spaces earlier in the grid, if they can fit ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)).

```css
.chars{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 20% 40%;
    grid-auto-flow: dense; /* new */
}

/* Setting all images of characters to fit in their cells. */
.chars img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.char1-img, .char3-img, .char5-img{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    grid-area: auto/1/auto/1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.char1-content,.char3-content,.char5-content{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-area: auto/2/auto/ span 3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.char2-img,.char4-img,.char6-img{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    grid-area: auto/3/auto/3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.char2-content,.char4-content,.char6-content{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-area: auto/1/auto/ span 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="chars">
  <div class="char1-img">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
  </div>
  <div class="char1-content">
    <p>
      Leon Harper or rather Leona Harper is part of a creed of Assassins and spies who have the uncanny
      ability to morph into any face they desire so as long as it is of the same gender and once they are
      in
      contact of it with the intent of morphing, Leona however is special even among her peers due to her
      ability to not only swap faces but also into one of any man or woman this has undoubtedly led her to
      be
      one of the most proficient and competent among the rest despite being a new recruit placing her in
      high
      regards for the Elders in the Creed.
      Much to the confusion surrounding her actual gender she has occasionally put out that she prefers to
      spend most of her time as a woman and to be addressed as Leona rather than her male counterpart
      "Leon".
      Whatever the case may be no one can deny her stunningly enchanting appearance regardless of what she
      chooses to go by.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char2-img">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
  </div>
  <div class="char2-content">
    <p>
      Elizabeth Burnley, a once-promising doctor, scientist, and scholar in a world where those
      professions are distant memories. Raised in a post-apocalyptic realm ravaged by a relentless virus,
      Elizabeth's life took a tragic turn when she lost her father to the very disease he fought to cure.
      As she now navigates a harsh existence within a hidden vault, her journey as a doctor accompanying
      search parties outside takes an unexpected turn, challenging her to adapt and survive in a world
      where danger and mystery lurk at every corner.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char3-img">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
  </div>
  <div class="char3-content">
    <p>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
      born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
      great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
      avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
      pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
      circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
      example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
      from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char4-img">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
  </div>
  <div class="char4-content">
    <p>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
      born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
      great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
      avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
      pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
      circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
      example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
      from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char5-img">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
  </div>
  <div class="char5-content">
    <p>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
      born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
      great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
      avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
      pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
      circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
      example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
      from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="char6-img">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
  </div>
  <div class="char6-content">
    <p>
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
      born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
      great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
      avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
      pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
      circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
      example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
      from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
      annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```